# How to ensure state is not stale in React hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The buttons i create using below seems to lag in the `selectedButtonIdx` value.

Is the `toggleSelected` not complete by the time `getClass` is called ?

```
function ButtonGroup(props) {
    const [selectedButtonIdx,setIdx]=useState(props.loadCurrentAsIndex);

    const toggleSelected = (e) => {
        setIdx(parseInt(e.target.dataset.index));
        props.onclick(e);
    };

    const getClass = (index) => {
        return (selectedButtonIdx === index) ? classnames('current', props.btnClass)
            : classnames(props.btnClass)
    };

    let buttons = props.buttons.map((b, idx) => <Button key={idx} value={b.value} index={idx} text={b.text}
                                                        onclick={e => toggleSelected(e)}
                                                        btnClass={getClass(idx)}/>);

    return (
        <div>
            {buttons}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Every onclick is expected to show the user which button in the group was clicked by changing its class.

Comment: This is most likely because `useState` is asynchronous [as answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54069332/11929924).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function setIdx, returned from useState is asynchronous, this means that it may be not be finished by the time you run your next function (as you guessed).

Take a look at [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) it allows you to specify a function to run once an item in your state changes, this method will ensure your functions are called in the right order.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at this,

```
<Button 
  key={idx} 
  value={b.value} 
  index={idx} 
  text={b.text}
  onclick={e => toggleSelected(e)}
  btnClass={getClass(idx)}
/>
```

`Button` is your custom component,

Two things to notice here,

1. You have provided `onclick` (`c` is small) props, in you actual component it should be `onClick={props.onclick}`
2. You have used `e.target.dataset.index`, to work with `dataset` we should have attribute with `data-` prefix. So your `index` should be `data-index` in your actual component.

So finally your `Button` component should be,

```
const Button = (props) => {
  return <button text={props.text} data-index={props.index} onClick={props.onclick} className={props.btnClass}>{props.value}</button>
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vibhqo)

Answer (score 0):

By now I don't see anything wrong here.

How it works:

1. initial render happens, `onClick` event listener is bound
2. user clicks a button, event handler calls `setIdx` triggering new render
3. new render is initiated, brand new `selectedButtonIdx` is used for rendering(and for `getClass` call as well)

See, there is no reason to worry about if `setIdx` is sync function or async.